# How to close Windows Form in powershell?

Tags: windows, forms, powershell

i'm working on a script to have an access control on a certain Programm in this example the calculator

When you start the Program(script) the script generates a text file with username and timestamp. If a second person tries to access, the script checks if this text file exists and gives out the username and the timestamp with the wish to try it later. If the file doesnt exist you have access to the program and the file will be generated. When you close the program the file will be removed.

I'm working with some windows forms to include an ingnore function and to exit the script.

The problem is that the windows forms do not close after you hit the ignore button on both forms.

Ive got no idea how to fix it.

Code:

```
##### further functions #####

Function Warnung {
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "System.Windows.Forms")

$Form1.text = "Warning!"
$Form1.Width = 300
$Form1.Height = 200

$Text = New-Object Windows.Forms.Label
$Text.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point 75,30
$Text.Size = New-Object Drawing.Point 200,30
$Text.text = "Am $timestamp hat sich" 

$Text2 = New-Object Windows.Forms.Label
$Text2.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point 75,60
$Text2.Size = New-Object Drawing.Point 200,30
$Text2.text = "$user"

$Text3 = New-Object Windows.Forms.Label
$Text3.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point 75,90
$Text3.Size = New-Object Drawing.Point 200,30
$Text3.text = "im calculator angemeldet!"

$Close = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$Close.text = "Close"
$Close.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point 20,120
$Close.add_click({$Form1.Close()})

$Taskmgr = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$Taskmgr.text = "Taskmgr"
$Taskmgr.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point 105,120
$Taskmgr.add_click({Taskmgr})

$Ignore = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$Ignore.text = "Ignore"
$Ignore.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point 190,120
$Ignore.add_click({Warning2})

$Form1.controls.add($Close)
$Form1.controls.add($Taskmgr)
$Form1.controls.add($Ignore)
$Form1.controls.add($Text)
$Form1.controls.add($Text2)
$Form1.controls.add($Text3)
$Form1.ShowDialog()
}

Function Taskmgr{
$Form1.Close() 
Start-process taskmgr.exe
}

Function Ign2{
$Form2.Close() 
$Form1.Close() 
Remove-Item C:\users\heisem\desktop\test.txt
$date = Get-Date
$file = "C:\users\heisem\desktop\test.txt"
$env:username | set-content $file
$date | add-content $file
}

Function Warning2 {

$Form2.text = "Warnung!"
$Form2.Width = 300
$Form2.Height = 200

$Text4 = New-Object Windows.Forms.Label
$Text4.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point 40,30
$Text4.Size = New-Object Drawing.Point 200,70
$Text4.text = "Sind Sie sich sicher, dass Sie $user übergehen möchten?" 
               "Haben Sie $user angesprochen
                ob diese(r) den Passwortsafe verlassen kann/hat?" 

$Close2 = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$Close2.text = "Close"
$Close2.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point 20,120
$Close2.add_click({$Form2.Close()})

$Ignore2 = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$Ignore2.text = "Ignore"
$Ignore2.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point 190,120
$Ignore2.add_click({Ign2})

$Form2.controls.add($Close2)
$Form2.controls.add($Ignore2)
$Form2.controls.add($Text4)
$Form2.ShowDialog()
}            

##### Main function #####

[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
$Form1 = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$Form2 = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form    

if (Test-Path C:\users\heisem\desktop\test.txt) {

$user = Get-content "C:\users\heisem\desktop\test.txt" -totalcount 1 
$timestamp = Get-Content "C:\users\heisem\desktop\test.txt" | Select-Object -Skip 1
Warnung 
Start-Process calc.exe -Wait                   
Remove-Item C:\users\heisem\desktop\test.txt 

} else {

$datum = Get-Date
$datei = "C:\users\heisem\desktop\test.txt"
$env:username | set-content $datei
$datum | add-content $datei
Start-Process calc.exe -Wait
Remove-Item C:\users\heisem\desktop\test.txt    
}
```

Comment: Im guessing you are having a scope issue in that `$Form1` and `$Form2` are created in one function but you are trying to access them in another. The forms are not accessible to `Ign2`

Comment: That was also my thought but without using function there is no benifit. I edited the Code above.

Answer (score 0):

It is something to do with the `-Wait` parameter you're using when calling `calc.exe`. You don't experience the problem in the function where you call `taskmgr.exe` because you don't use `-Wait`.

I would also take the `$Form1` and `$Form2` definitions out of the local function scopes so each can have access to them globally.

Rather wildly guessing, I suppose the `-Wait` parameter doesn't allow the preceding code to complete execution until the function exits i.e. the framework is making a decision that certain references still need to exist while the process you invoked exists.

```powershell
##### further functions #####

Function Warnung {
    [reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "System.Windows.Forms")

    $Form1.text = "Warning!"
    $Form1.Width = 300
    $Form1.Height = 200

    $Text = New-Object Windows.Forms.Label
    $Text.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point 75,30
    $Text.Size = New-Object Drawing.Point 200,30
    $Text.text = "Am $timestamp hat sich" 

    $Text2 = New-Object Windows.Forms.Label
    $Text2.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point 75,60
    $Text2.Size = New-Object Drawing.Point 200,30
    $Text2.text = "$user"

    $Text3 = New-Object Windows.Forms.Label
    $Text3.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point 75,90
    $Text3.Size = New-Object Drawing.Point 200,30
    $Text3.text = "im calculator angemeldet!"

    $Close = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
    $Close.text = "Close"
    $Close.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point 20,120
    $Close.add_click({$Form1.Close()})

    $Taskmgr = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
    $Taskmgr.text = "Taskmgr"
    $Taskmgr.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point 105,120
    $Taskmgr.add_click({Taskmgr})

    $Ignore = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
    $Ignore.text = "Ignore"
    $Ignore.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point 190,120
    $Ignore.add_click({Warning2})

    $Form1.controls.add($Close)
    $Form1.controls.add($Taskmgr)
    $Form1.controls.add($Ignore)
    $Form1.controls.add($Text)
    $Form1.controls.add($Text2)
    $Form1.controls.add($Text3)
    $Form1.ShowDialog()
}

Function Taskmgr{
    $Form1.Close() ### IT WORKS HERE
    Start-process taskmgr.exe
}

Function Ign2{
    $Form2.Close() ### HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    $Form1.Close() ### THE FORMS DO NOT CLOSE
    Remove-Item C:\users\heisem\desktop\test.txt
    $date = Get-Date
    $file = "C:\users\heisem\desktop\test.txt"
    $env:username | set-content $file
    $date | add-content $file
    Start-Process calc.exe
    Remove-Item C:\users\heisem\desktop\test.txt
}

Function Warning2 {

    $Form2.text = "Warnung!"
    $Form2.Width = 300
    $Form2.Height = 200

    $Text4 = New-Object Windows.Forms.Label
    $Text4.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point 40,30
    $Text4.Size = New-Object Drawing.Point 200,70
    $Text4.text = "Sind Sie sich sicher, dass Sie $user übergehen möchten?" 
                   "Haben Sie $user angesprochen
                    ob diese(r) den Passwortsafe verlassen kann/hat?" 

    $Close2 = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
    $Close2.text = "Close"
    $Close2.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point 20,120
    $Close2.add_click({$Form2.Close()})

    $Ignore2 = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
    $Ignore2.text = "Ignore"
    $Ignore2.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point 190,120
    $Ignore2.add_click({Ign2})

    $Form2.controls.add($Close2)
    $Form2.controls.add($Ignore2)
    $Form2.controls.add($Text4)
    $Form2.ShowDialog()
}            

##### Main function #####

[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
$Form1 = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$Form2 = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form    

if (Test-Path C:\users\heisem\desktop\test.txt) {

    $user = Get-content "C:\users\heisem\desktop\test.txt" -totalcount 1 
    $timestamp = Get-Content "C:\users\heisem\desktop\test.txt" | Select-Object -Skip 1
    Warnung 

} else {

    $datum = Get-Date
    $datei = "C:\users\heisem\desktop\test.txt"
    $env:username | set-content $datei
    $datum | add-content $datei
    Start-Process calc.exe -Wait
    Remove-Item C:\users\heisem\desktop\test.txt    
}
```

Comment: I tested your code but that didnt solve the problem.

Comment: Would you not need `$` in front of `Form1` and `Form2` @arco444 @freakies

Comment: matt - Well spotted, thank you. Copying error on my behalf. @freakies, I've included the entire script as I tested it, I had also juggled the code. See if that helps. Be sure to test in a fresh PowerShell window.

Comment: Ok your version works :) as you said the `-Wait(in IGN2)` causes the problem, but i need it, because now the `Remove-Item` Command will be instantly executed . This Command is responsible for blocking the access to the calculator because a second person checks with the `IF` if somebody is working in the program and get an alert. Actually: It become a problem when person2 has ignored the alert (deleting the txt file instantly) and person3 tries to open the calculator (becomes access because file doesnt exist)

Comment: I put the Start-Process and Remove-Item Command in the Main Function after calling function Warning. Ive edited the Question Post Code above. now i get access to the calc when im hitting the close buttom in the first window...... thinking...